# Prove by definition $g(x)=x^4$ at $p=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove by definition that the given function is continuous at the given point.
$g(x)=x^4$, at $p=1$

Here is my attempt at proof, and I'm mostly interested in validity of my proof.

$\lim _{x\to p}g\left(x\right)=g\left(p\right)\Leftrightarrow \left(\forall \epsilon >0\right)\left(\exists \delta >0\right):\:\left(0<\left|x-p\right|<\delta \:\wedge \:x\in D_g\right)\Rightarrow \left|g\left(x\right)-g\left(p\right)\right|<\epsilon$

Proof:

1. $\lim _{x\to 1}x^4=g\left(1\right)\Leftrightarrow \left(\forall \epsilon >0\right)\left(\exists \delta >0\right):\:\left(0<\left|x-1\right|<\delta \:\wedge \:x\in D_g\right)\Rightarrow \left|\left(x^4\right)-\left(1\right)^4\right|<\epsilon$.
2. Let’s find a "$\delta$" in function of "$ \epsilon$".
   $\left|x^4-1\right|=\left|x-1\right|\left|\left(x+1\right)\left(x^2+1\right)\right|<\epsilon $.
3. By the thesis, we have $\left|x-1\right|<\delta$.
4. Let’s limit $\left|\left(x+1\right)\left(x^2+1\right)\right|$ to find $k>0$, such that $\left|\left(x+1\right)\left(x^2+1\right)\right|<k$.
5. $\left|x-1\right|<\delta _1=1\:\Leftrightarrow \left|x-1\right|<1\:\Leftrightarrow -1<x-1<1\:\Leftrightarrow 0<x<2\:\Leftrightarrow \left|x+1\right|\left|x^2+1\right|<9$
6. Let’s multiply the inequalities of 3. and 5. So we'll have:
   $\left|x-1\right|\left|x+1\right|\left|x^2+1\right|<9\delta =\epsilon $.
7. Making $9\delta = \epsilon \Rightarrow \delta = \frac{\epsilon }{9}$.
8. We chose $\delta =\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}=\{1, \frac{\epsilon }{9}\}$.

$\Box$

Comment: From $0<x<2$ you can obtain $|x+1||x^2+1|<15$. So let $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/15\}$. The idea of your proof is totolly right.

Comment: @YanPeng How did you get to $<15$? Can you help me get that result?